# Print a result without square brackets

Tags: python

When I create a list of arrays in Python and print out the result of the first index, why does it print the square brackets too?

```
    people = [
    ["Fredrick", 23],
    ["Lorenzo", 13],
    ["Francesco", 13],
    ["Giovanna", 9]
]

print(f"{people[0]}")
```

> Output: ['Fredrick', 23]

Comment: `people[0]` is the list `['Fredrick', 23]`, and lists get printed with square brackets around, just like you enter them, so what surprises you here? Did you expect anything different?

Comment: How would i print them without the square brackets ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us your expected output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [tour], and browse the [Help] to get an insight of how to ask a good question. I have edited your post title so it tells us about your actual question, instead of your own generic title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined an array with arrays as elements. That's why you get the array ['Fredrick', 23] when you access the first index of people array. This is equivalent with accessing the first item of the array

```
>> array = [10, 20, 30]
>> print array[0]
>> 10
```

In your case the first element is the array:

```
>> ['Fredrick', 23]
```

An alternative approach could be:

```
# map is another (more appropriate) 
# data structure to store this data. 
people = {
    'Fredrick': 23,
    'Lorenzo': 13,
    'Francesco': 13,
    'Giovanna': 9
}

for name, age in people.items():
    # iterate through all map items
    # and print out each person's name and age.
    # Note: you need to convert the age from int to string
    # in order to concatenate it.
    print name + ", " + str(people[name])
```

Comment: people_map.items() is not defined ?

Comment: In my local environment  I used people_map instead of people and I forgot to update this line of code. Sorry! Now its fixed

Answer (score 1):

You created `people` which is a list of lists. Then you refer to the f-string `f"{people[0]}"`. When you reference it, the expression `people[0]` is evaluated and is found to be the list `["Fredrick", 23]`. That is then converted to a string--remember, this is an f-string. The double-quotes around `Fredrick` are converted to single-quotes, according to the Python standard, where either single- or double-quotes may be used to denote a string but they are alternated for strings-within-strings. Python wants to put double-quotes around the entire string whenever its representation is needed, so to alternate the type of quotes, single-quotes are used. So the final f-string is

```
"['Fredrick', 23]"
```

Remember, what is inside the string is a representation of the list inside `people`. Python adds the brackets so everyone knows that is indeed a list. Python could have done it differently, but this makes the list nature explicit, and the second rule in [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is

> Explicit is better than implicit.

So the brackets are shown. If you do not want the brackets, there are several ways to remove them. The simplest way to print that f-string without the brackets is probably

```
print(f"{people[0]}"[1:-1])
```

which prints

```
'Fredrick', 23
```

That code prints the string but removes the first and last characters, which are the brackets. If you do not understand [Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation#509295) you should research it--this is one of Python's strengths in string handling.

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
people = [
    ["Fredrick", 23],
    ["Lorenzo", 13],
    ["Francesco", 13],
    ["Giovanna", 9]
]
```

Creates a list of lists, `people[0]` gives the first value - which is the list `["Fredrick", 23]`. When printing a list python (by default) print the brackets as well.